# VBA Renomear todos os arquivos que começam com "Rel"

Tags: vba

Olá
Preciso gerar um código que renomeie todos os arquivos de uma pasta que comecem com "relat" para "X-CT". 
O restante do nome do arquivo, inclusive a extenção ".DOC .PDF . XLS" continuaram inalteradas.

Comment: Isso precisa ser na Macro do Excel, pois a renomeação acontece após o evento de criação destes mesmos arquivos. Apos renomear, a Macro irá gerar outro lote de arquivos que começam com "relat", depois preciso renomear novamente.... e assim por diante;

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o código abaixo te ajude. Basicamente, faz um loop pelos arquivos de um diretório e substitui, no nome de cada arquivo, a sequência de caracteres que deseja substituir pela nova.

Segue o código com a edição proposta pelo usuário @Evert:

```
Sub changeFileName(ByVal srtExtencion as String)

Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFile As String

  strFolder = "C:\SomeFolder\"
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*." & strExtension)
  Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    If InStr(strFile, "relat") > 0 Then
      Name strFolder & strFile As strFolder & Replace(strFile, "relat", "X-CT")
    End If
    strFile = Dir()
  Loop

End Sub
```

Depois chame a função com a extensão desejada:

```
changeFileName doc
changeFileName pdf
changeFileName xls
```

Extraí essa solução [deste fórum](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/rename-part-file-vba-t1997867.html), junto da edição proposta pelo usuário @Evert

Comment: Não consigo editar sua resposta... mas se puder, edite e coloque código que nosso amigo precisa e depois apagarei minha resposta.

Comment: Edições feitas! Agradeço pela sugestão.
Abraços!